# react native android crashes when onResume

Tags: android, react-native, android-multidex

When the app is sent to background the next time that comes active(onResume) just dies without any errors either in the devtools(chrome) or logcat(android-studio). I tried to do backward steps on my changes to see if that breaks it but I couldn't find anything I have 2 days already working on this but did get any luck.

Using React 15.1.0 and React Native 0.27.2

Additionally im using google play services and enable multidex

As long as the app didn't go to onPause every thing works fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please Make sure that your device is properly connected to ADB, the Android Debug Bridge, by using `adb devices`
2. Then Run `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`
3. Then `Reload JS`